# Recommended Git tools for windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, git

I have only ever used VSS (uggh, I know) and Team Foundation Server for source control management on windows. I develop in c# using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE. I now have a requirement to use Git on my next project.

Can you please  recommend a Git tool out there? I know this question has been asked before on SOF but it seems to be a bit dated. Also considering that I have only ever used repositories coming out of the MS stable, I was hoping there is a similar GUI or VS add-on from a GIT that helps me adapt.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)  is very complete and it also integrates very well in Visual Studio 2010.

For a comparison between [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) and GitExtensions, take a look to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011893/tortoisegit-vs-git-extensions)

Both TortoiseGit and GitExtensions are open source.

[Here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/t/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools.html) you can find a list of available frontends.

I personally suggest GitExtensions, which also have a decent set of shortcuts (I hate to switch from keyboard to mouse while developing).

Take a look to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows)  as well, you may find it useful.

#### Update

I quit using GitExtension when I discovered [SmartGIT](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/). I highly suggest to take into consideration it as well: it does not integrate with Windows File Explorer (which now I consider a benefit) and it has a very polished and smart GUI.

Comment: +1 I think GitExtensions + dropping to command-line git using the bundled MSysGit is the best option. I really disliked TortoiseGit. TortoiseSVN works wonderfully with SVN, but trying to use the same interface with git just doesn't work.

Comment: @AbeVoelker I completely agree. For example, while GitExtensions is great in managing the git index, TortoiseGit tries to mime SVN and somehow hides the existence of it. Actually, I never uninstalled TortoiseGit just because I like the "Git Bash Here" menu item in Explorer context menu, but it happens I never use any other features: GitExtensions+command line are enough to me.

Answer (score 4):

I still use the command line from [Git-bash](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) as sometime.

**Git-bash** make you powerful on Git in advance, and you still have the knowledge when you have other system which not Windows. For **TortoiseGit**, I like to see graph virtualization -- it will show the relation between code branch that make you easy to understand, also statistic.

Comment: +1 and I also recommend you check out the [Git Extensions for Visual Studio](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)

Comment: @Pete I am currently looking at Git Extensions for Visual Studio. They do have support for 2010 as well as Windows Explorer integration. worth looking into. Thanks.

Comment: +1 same with you brother. I use gitbash for general git commands and only use Tortoise GIT for resolve conflict and see the differences between file. :)

Answer (score 3):

[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) is awesome :) We use it where I work and it really helps streamline merge conflicts and resolution. Otherwise, you can always download eclipse and use eGit, but it's relatively buggy.

I highly recommend reading through the Git Guide on StackOverflow:

[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

It covers all the GUI Tools, processes, references, and other resources.

Comment: Might want to mention SmartGit is not free for commercial purposes

Comment: Correct, it's not free, it's around $70. However, I've found the benefits make up for the cost.

Comment: Actually, it is completely free for non-commercial projects. And it supports Mercurial as well. (I still prefere GitExtension, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Never been a fan of Git (I prefer using SVN and hg), but considering both TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHG are quite good, I'd recommend trying [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/), which is a port of TortoiseSVN to work with Git instead of SVN.